# Simple CMakeLists.txt that reflects typical directory structure (/src, /inc, /bin subdirectories)

Tags: cmake

I am struggling to make a CMakeList.txt file to reflect a simple, typical makefile. The original is here http://pastebin.com/S9Czr1pt .

I tried many things (like SET(SOURCE ... and SET(HEADERS... ) to add /src, /lib and /third-party//include ), but I have no luck.

Can anyone either help me out or point to a tutorial that does this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an out of the blue skeleton - please see the [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/) for details of each function:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
# Project name, can be used as target name too
project(Example)

# Search all .cpp files within src - recursive!
# You can add all source files by hand here too
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS "src/*.cpp")

# Add include path (you can also add it's sub directories
include_directories("include")

# Search for packages -- PLEASE NOTE: many libraries provide alternative's to this
# which often provide more functionality
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
# TODO: add proper pkg modul search info's and change the variable's name
pkg_search_module(PACKAGE_NO1 ...)

# Show some messages (optional)
if( (PACKAGE_NO1 )
    include_directories(${(PACKAGE_NO1_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message(STATUS "Using OpenSSL ${(PACKAGE_NO1_VERSION}")
else()
    # do error handling
endif()

# Add compiler flags
add_definitions(-std=c++11 -Wall) # -g O3 etc are added according to Release / Debug compilation

# Build a executable target (1st param: Target name; 2nd: source files)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS})
```